# Multiple resources of the same type with the same name in a single Kubernetes namespace?

Tags: kubectl, operator-sdk, operator-lifecycle-manager

I've encountered a cluster which has multiple `PackageManifest` resources of the same name in the same namespace. There seem to be two `CatalogSource`s and there is some overlap in the components they define.

```
$ kubectl get packagemanifest -n olm | grep rho | sort
rhoas-operator                                     Community Operators              20d
rhods-operator                                     Red Hat OpenShift Data Science   16h
rhods-operator                                     Red Hat Operators                20d
rhods-prometheus-operator                          Red Hat OpenShift Data Science   16h
rhods-prometheus-operator                          Red Hat Operators                20d
```

Querying by kind, name, and namespace seems to give one of the two at random.

```
$ kubectl get packagemanifest/rhods-operator -n olm
NAME             CATALOG                          AGE
rhods-operator   Red Hat OpenShift Data Science   16h
$ kubectl get packagemanifest/rhods-operator -n olm
NAME             CATALOG             AGE
rhods-operator   Red Hat Operators   20d
```

What I am observing completely breaks my long-held belief, supported by documentation, that

> Each object in your cluster has a Name that is unique for that type of resource. Every Kubernetes object also has a UID that is unique across your whole cluster.
>
> For example, you can only have one Pod named myapp-1234 within the same namespace, but you can have one Pod and one Deployment that are each named myapp-1234.
>
> ~~ https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/

Is what I am happening a misconfiguration? Why does Kubernetes allow it? Is OLM doing something nefarious?

### Investigating kind and apiVersion

```
$ kubectl get packagemanifest --namespace=olm --output=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.kind}{'\t'}{.apiVersion}{'\t'}{.metadata.name}{'\n'}{end}" | grep rho | sort
PackageManifest packages.operators.coreos.com/v1        rhoas-operator
PackageManifest packages.operators.coreos.com/v1        rhods-operator
PackageManifest packages.operators.coreos.com/v1        rhods-operator
PackageManifest packages.operators.coreos.com/v1        rhods-prometheus-operator
PackageManifest packages.operators.coreos.com/v1        rhods-prometheus-operator
```

Comment: I suspect the shortname (`packagemanifest`) is the same but the CRD `kind` and|or `apiVersion` differ? Can you enumerate these `kubectl get packagemanifest --namespace=olm --output=jsonpath="{range .items[*}}{.kind}{'\t'}{.apiVersion}{'\t'}{.metadata.name}{'\n'}{end}"`?

Comment: @DazWilkin That's not it, they are completely the same in `kind` and `apiVersion` attributes. See end of edited question for the listing. I had to fix a small typo (wrong closing square brace) in your query, btw.

Comment: Apologies for the typo, I made it up as I wrote the comment and can't edit the comment.

Comment: I've reported this as OLM bug at https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/issues/3161